# how to lock perticular screen orientation in Blackberry storm 2

Tags: landscape, screen-orientation, blackberry-storm, landscape-portrait

in my application there are around 7 to 8 screen and i want to do that particular 2 or 3 screen orientation change and other remain still in `Portrait View`.

```
i have implemented this `int direction = Display.DIRECTION_NORTH;
    Ui.getUiEngineInstance().setAcceptableDirections(direction);`
```

it working fine at first time application start but when `setAcceptableDirections` method call and set orientation for particular screen that orientation set for all screen in this application . i cant change orientation for particular screen

so is it possible to change pariticular screen orientation in blackberry ? 
please help me if any one have any idea .